# Unable to view API response in Charles web proxy(4.6.1) when connected to Android app running in Samsung tabA7

Tags: charles-proxy

I have installed charles proxy Certificate on Android Samsung tabA7.
Followed the steps:https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121

When i launch the app on device, Charles Web proxy display the API responses as Unknown Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue and view the actual response.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the app you need to modify the manifest of Android app otherwise it won't work as Applications don't allow it by default.

Refer Charles documentation: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Android:

As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in order to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL Proxying. This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps that you control.

Add a file res/xml/network_security_config.xml to your app:

```
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```

Then add a reference to this file in your app's manifest, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```